# Make text stay within vertical progress bar + vertical align: center

Tags: css

I'm having two problems that I can't figure out.

**First:** I want the text to stay within the main div, so when the progress bar's height is near the bottom, it won't go outside.

**Second:** Is there any way to vertically center the text so that it works with the first problem/solution?

https://jsfiddle.net/zv4xkcrr/

```js
$(function() {
  function refill() {
    $( "#progressBar_fill" ).animate({
     height: "100%"
    }, 5000, function() {
      $( "#progressBar_fill" ).animate({
        height: "0%"
      }, 5000, function() {
        refill();
      });
    });
 }
  refill();
});
```

```css
#progressBar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 80%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 11px;
  top: 10%;
  left: 14px;
  background: rgba(255, 72, 72, 0.04) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
#progressBar_fill {
  width: inherit;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 11px;
  height: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
#progressBar_fill span {
  vertical-align: middle
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progressBar">
  <div id="progressBar_fill">
    <span>50%</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first : `#progressBar { overflow: hidden;}`
second: place `<span>50%</span>` outside `#progressBar_fill` and add `positon: absolute; top: 50%;` to this element

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say is vertically align within the green bar, so it follows it up and down.

Comment: Okay, then leave span tag inside #progressBar_fill; add position relative to  #progressBar_fill; add left: 0; to span element (do not remove previously added code)

Comment: Thank you :), so there isn't really IE8 compatible solution?

Comment: this should work on IE8: https://jsfiddle.net/ng0o52d1/1/ ; Unfortunately you will have to test it somewhere else, not at jsfiddle.net . You have used rgba in your code. That wont work in IE8

Comment: @user3660683 You can remove some redundant CSS [like this example](https://jsfiddle.net/dLd0mz90/). For instance `vertical-align: middle
  display: inline-block;` isn't doing anything useful.

Comment: @Danko Much appreciated :) RGBA was copy-paste error due to firefox automatically converting to RGBA, it was simply color: green at first.

Answer (score 0):

Take the span out of the progressbar_fill and update the span position.
Here's a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/1krggjsq/1/

```js
$(function() {
  function refill() {
    $( "#progressBar_fill" ).animate({
     height: "100%"
    }, 5000, function() {
      $( "#progressBar_fill" ).animate({
        height: "0%"
      }, 5000, function() {
        refill();
      });
    });
 }
  refill();
});
```

```css
#progressBar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 80%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 11px;
  top: 10%;
  left: 14px;
  background: rgba(255, 72, 72, 0.04);
}
#progressBar_fill {
  width: inherit;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 11px;
  height: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
#progressBar span {
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div id="progressBar">
  <span>50%</span>
  <div id="progressBar_fill">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

using `display: table; and table-cell` will help, you need to add on more extra tag like i did `<em>` , by using this method your content will always remain in middle

```js
$(function() {
  function refill() {
    $("#progressBar_fill").animate({
      height: "100%"
    }, 5000, function() {
      $("#progressBar_fill").animate({
        height: "0%"
      }, 5000, function() {
        refill();
      });
    });
  }
  refill();
});
```

```css
#progressBar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 80%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 11px;
  top: 10%;
  left: 14px;
  background: rgba(255, 72, 72, 0.04) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
#progressBar_fill {
  width: inherit;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 11px;
  height: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
#progressBar_fill span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
#progressBar_fill span em {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progressBar">
  <div id="progressBar_fill">
    <span><em>50%</em></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved one of the problems :) Any way to make the text stay within the main div so it remains visible at all times?

Comment: 50% is within the parent div,

Answer (score 0):

Use these HTML, instead of yours.

look at these fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zv4xkcrr/3/

used some part of @Danko's code.

```
<div id="progressBar" style="overflow:hidden;">
   <span class="spanCenter">50%</span>
  <div id="progressBar_fill">   
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS looks like

```
.spanCenter
{
  position:absolute; 
  top:50%;
  z-index:10000;
}
```